# Java, Comparing minutes in if statement - not getting desired results

Tags: java, javafx, compare, user-input

Maybe it is just my state of mind/frustration at the moment, but my google searches and stackoverflow results aren't helping me.

I am wanting to validate that the minutes part of a time input is equal to either 00 or 30.

I am still getting a handle on Java and programming in general so sometimes I don't know the correct terminology to begin a search so I apologize if this has been asked and answered.

Any answers should be somewhere between beginner and intermediate - if I don't understand I will attempt to figure it out on my own before just replying.

This is a snippet of my latest attempt:

```
else if(timePart.getMinute() != 0 || 
        timePart.getMinute() != 30 ||
        appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 0 ||
        appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 30)
{
    System.out.println(timePart.getMinute());
    System.out.println(appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute());
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Correct the minutes");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("You are only allowed to enter the start and end time minutes on the hour or half hour (ie :00 or :30).");
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

I included the System.out to just test what the different results were - both will print a 0 for 9:00 AM and 30 for 9:30 AM for example.

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly but my alert is always popping up even when a valid time is input.

Comment: why are you using this `appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 0`

Comment: You issue is in your boolean logic.  timePart.getMinute() != 0 || timePart.getMinute() != 30  if the value is 30 then the != 0 is true so the statement is true - you need to use AND not OR - timePart.getMinute() != 0 && timePart.getMinute() != 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is always true.

```
    if (timePart.getMinute() != 0 || 
        timePart.getMinute() != 30 || 
        appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 0 ||
        appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 30 )
```

It always pops up because minute is always different then 0 OR different then 30.

For example when timePart.getMinute() is 0 then it's different then 30 and the other way around.
You should show popup only when :

```
  if ((timePart.getMinute() == 0 || timePart.getMinute() == 30 || ...) == false)
```

or shorter

```
 if (!(timePart.getMinute() == 0 || timePart.getMinute() == 30 ||...))
```

or changing your or to an and:

```
 if (timePart.getMinute() != 0 && timePart.getMinute() != 30 || ...)
```

Comment: wow - what a day.  Thanks, I can't believe I missed that...sigh

Answer (score 1):

Change to and comparison - not or:

```
else if(timePart.getMinute() != 0 && timePart.getMinute() != 30 &&
                    appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 0 &&
                    appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 30
                    )
            {
                System.out.println(timePart.getMinute());
                System.out.println(appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute());
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Correct the minutes");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("You are only allowed to enter the start and end time minutes on the hour or half hour (ie :00 or :30).");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

To check, if the minutes are divisible by `30` you could use the `%` operator. this way you avoid checking the minutes value for both `0` and `30`:

```
else if(timePart.getMinute() % 30 != 0
        || appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() % 30 != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition is:

```
else if((timePart.getMinute() != 0 && timePart.getMinute() != 30) ||
                    (appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 0 &&
                    appointment.getSqlStartDateTime().toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute() != 30)
                    )
```

Comment: Both start and end time should validate, the relationship is (start !=0 && start != 30) || (end != 0 && end != 30)